# Should we use "opinion of" or "opinion on"?

Tags: prepositions

What preposition should we use after *opinion*? Which of the following is correct:

> 1. What is your opinion on this book?
> 2. What is your opinion of this book?

Also, what is the correct way of saying the following:

> We surveyed drivers' opinion on this device?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In British English you might use 'of' for a specific thing, eg. a book or person, and 'on' for a broad topic, eg. 'your opinion on string theory'.

But it's not a very strong rule, I wouldn't feel that either was wrong. This may be the effect of American English usage of 'on'.

To your specific question,

> We surveyed drivers' opinion on this device?

**of**  might be less ambiguous about whether you were talking about their opinion of the device, or you used the device for the survey.  Does "We surveyed drivers opinions **on** twitter" mean you asked them about twitter or you used twitter to ask about something else?

Comment: Thanks @mgb. I understand... I should say _We surveyed drivers' opinion of this device?_

Comment: For example: I do not give my private opinion **of** my nearest relations.

Comment: @Stat-R - yes, I would

Comment: @Stat-R: You've got mgb's distinction right, in that *this device* is a **specific thing**, so opinions would normally be *of it*. But it should always be *drivers' **opinions*** in the plural for your construction.

Comment: @Hannele - BE and AE are standard abbrev here for British English and American English - it actually makes answers more concise and readable

Comment: I don't there there's any difference between British and American usage here.

Comment: @PeterShor - I thought AE pretty much used 'on' everywhere?

Comment: I don't. Maybe some areas of the U.S. might (things like this can vary regionally), but "of" and "on" are both used in the Northeast.

Comment: @mgb I respectfully disagree - the first usage should always be expanded, in case of a new user of the site. AE & BE _are_ fairly common, but still obtuse to those who aren't familiar with the convention. To keep growing as a Q&A forum, we should be keeping new users in mind - [more than 96% of the users of this site have less the 200 reputation](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/35/week/english)!

Comment: @mgb However, the acronyms could be used effectively in a lengthy discussion over the differences between the two - say, first use in full, and further uses with the acronyms.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, when it is a broad topic, we can use 'on', but when it is a matter of 'good,or 'bad' we can use of. For example, "Your opinion of me does not define who I am". Another example can be, what is your opinion on politics.